# Restkit onDidFailWithError never get called

Tags: ios, restkit

I am trying to post an object with block. `OnDidFailWithError` never get called and it blew up.

This is the error i got:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[MyClass
>   objectLoader:didFailWithError:]: unrecognized selector sent to class

And here is my code:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject: myObj usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader){
    loader.targetObject = nil;
    loader.delegate = (id)self;
    loader.objectMapping = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider objectMappingForClass:[MyClass class]];

    loader.onDidFailWithError = ^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    };

    loader.onDidLoadObject = ^(id obj) {
        NSLog(@"Comment");
        NSLog(@"%@",obj);
    };

    loader.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response) {
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", [response bodyAsString]);
    };

    loader.onDidLoadObjects=^(NSArray* objects){
        //post notification
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"finish" object:nil];
    };

    loader.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON; // We want to send this request as JSON
    loader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;

    loader.serializationMapping = [RKObjectMapping serializationMappingUsingBlock:^(RKObjectMapping* mapping) {
        [mapping mapAttributes:@"field1", @"field2",nil];
    }];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't handle the error try this on **onDidLoadResponse**

```
    loader.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response) {

        NSLog(@"Response did arrive");
        if([response statusCode]>299){

            NSError *error = nil;
            id parsedResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[response body] options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
            NSLog(@"%@",parsedResponse);

        }

    };
```

Comment: Myclass is the name of the class which i do not want to disclosed online. I got the object loading success but just can't handle the error.

Comment: I just edited the answer, check if that helps you to debug what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the delegate to self, which is going to call those RestKit delegate methods on your current controller, not using the block you've created.